# inserting a view inside of a view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

how do you place a view inside of a view in android xml? I have come from a web development background so the closest example I can think of is placing div's inside of div's,  [something like this for example](http://g1.gstatic.com/android/market/com.onavo.android.onavoid/ss-480-4-0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't place Views inside Views (i.e. `ImageView` inside an `ImageView`).

You can place `Views` inside `ViewGroups` (i.e. an `ImageView` inside a `LinearLayout`).

Please check here for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html and here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: so are these additional views merely textviews with images inside them? for example in that image I posted the first 2 views had images placed inside

Comment: the second link you sent me answers my question perfectly, thanks for the help!

Comment: no problem! if you have any further problem or question, do not hesitate to ask (if you don't find any other solution anywhere :))

Answer (score 0):

You can't place views inside another view.

A View occupies a rectangular area on the screen and is responsible for drawing and event handling. View is the base class for widgets, which are used to create interactive UI components (buttons, text fields, etc.). The ViewGroup subclass is the base class for layouts, which are invisible containers that hold other Views (or other ViewGroups) and define their layout properties

some viewgroups are

AbsoluteLayout, AdapterView, FragmentBreadCrumbs, FrameLayout, GridLayout, LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, SlidingDrawer, Toolbar, TvView, CardView, etc